# Error in running a multi-level mixed effects model on microbiome data

Tags: r, linear-regression, linear-programming, mixed-models, multilevel-analysis

I have been trying do multi-level mixed effects model on the microbiome data I am working, but I keep getting the error below. What is frustrating is that, I don't encounter this error on my Windows OS which I use in the office, indicating that the problem may not be with the code. I am using a Mac OS.

```
Error in t(do.call(sparseMatrix, do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(blist),  : 
  invalid 'lazy' to 'R_sparse_transpose'
```